# add elements to onchange in javascript

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, prestashop, onchange

I am modifying a function in a prestashop product page. I need to add the combination price to the combination buttons. I was able to do this by adding the following code which overrides the default action.
The problem comes when the user clicks on one of the buttons. The url adds the combination identifier to the url (#/combination1). At this point the original button text replaces the text that I had set with my javascript call.

Example page : https://preprod17.groupepointsrezo.fr/bouquet-de-roses/29-68-bouquet-de-roses-rouges.html#/30-tailles_bouquets-simple_10_tiges

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {

    var productPrices = [];
    var productNames = [];
    var targetDivs = document.getElementById("add-to-cart-or-refresh").getElementsByClassName("radio-label");

   for (k in accessoriesTablePrice[randomMainProductId].combinations) {
    productPrices.push(accessoriesTablePrice[randomMainProductId].combinations[k].price);
};
   for (d in accessoriesTablePrice[randomMainProductId].combinations) {
 productNames.push(accessoriesTablePrice[randomMainProductId].combinations[d].name);
};
    for (i = 0; i < targetDivs.length; i++) {
         var targetDiv = targetDivs[i];
         if(productPrices[i] >=0) {
           targetDiv.innerHTML = productNames[i] + "<br>" + productPrices[i] + ",00 €";
         } 
    }
});
```

What I would like is the button texts to not change at all.
The javascript that I seem to need but which changes in text seems to be included in the following javascript code (found through the event listener in the google console)

```
(0,
    r.default)(document).ready(function() {
        (0,
        r.default)("body").on("change touchspin.on.startspin", ".product-variants *[name]", function(e) {
            o.default.emit("updateProduct", {
                eventType: "updatedProductCombination",
                event: e,
                resp: {},
                reason: {
                    productUrl: o.default.urls.pages.product || ""
                }
            })
        }),
```

I don't know how to proceed from here. Is there a way to add my code to this onchange event so that it continues to replace the original text?
Thanks for any an all help

Comment: ```At this point the original button text replaces the text that I had set with my javascript call.``` Where is the ```The original button text```? Where is the ```original button```? Where is the text you set with js call?

Comment: The original button texts are dynamically created from the product variant. They are found on my example page underneath the word "Taille". For example, "Large tige 75,00€". They are dynamically replaced by my two variables "productPrices" and "productNames"

Comment: The first solution: I think you should look for PrestaShop's solution to add your price to the button in the page instead of add your price in your custom js. 
Second solution: It is a silly solution but it should works. You can also store the price in the attribute of the button and add a change event listener to the button, whenever you change the button, you get the price again from the attribute and render it to the page again.

Comment: Thanks. I've already tried to find a prestashop solution. Couldn't figure it out. I will probably try your second solution. I'll let you know eventually.